# Border issues inside modal

Tags: html, css

I want there to be space above and below the 'offer' button in my modal. I first try to add a border to the bottom of it, 30 pixels, but its not showing up. The end of the modal is directly under the end of the button, there is no space between the two.

[image]

CSS

```
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#offerButton {
  border-bottom: 30px;
}

#inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#text1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML/ANGULAR

```
<body>
  <div id="text1">
    <h2 class="text-center" id="offer">Offer: <span>${{offerVal}}</span></h2>
    <h2 class="text-center" id="offer">Price: <span>${{price}}</span></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer text-center">
    <input type="range" min={{min}} max={{max}} class="slider" id="myRange" [(ngModel)]="offerVal" name="slider">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="offerButton" (click)="offer()">  Offer  </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why not give your button container an id and add padding to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following to get space between the offer button and modal end:

Apply `padding-bottom` on `slidecontainer` class.

```
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px 30px 20px;
}
```

Place the offer button inside div where you applied class `slidecontainer`.

```
<div class="slidecontainer text-center">
    <input type="range" min={{min}} max={{max}} class="slider" id="myRange"
           [(ngModel)]="offerVal" name="slider">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="offerButton"
            (click)="offer()">  Offer
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't apply the `border-bottom` on the button it will not solve your problem.

Also, you can't have the same id on two different elements so change the id of one of the h2 element where id is **offer**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding border-bottom to **offerButton** add margin to id **offerButton**
and,If you want space specific only top and bottom then add margin-top and margin-bottom

```css
#offerButton {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="text1">
    <h2 class="text-center" id="offer">Offer: <span>${{offerVal}}</span></h2>
    <h2 class="text-center" id="offer">Price: <span>${{price}}</span></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="slidecontainer text-center">
    <input type="range" min={{min}} max={{max}} class="slider" id="myRange" [(ngModel)]="offerVal" name="slider">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="offerButton" (click)="offer()">  Offer  </button>
  </div>
</body>
```